# Web Service (JaxB-WS) - Exception when null value enetered

Tags: xml, web-services, exception, jaxb, wsdl

I have created a basic Web Service with JAXB, when testing the basic functionality in Netbeans/Glassfish I noticed that if no value is entered it throws an exception because the value is null.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5kjyvqlzwy56vqm/Stackoverflow.png

I wish to be able to either make the variable not required OR return a more informative error exception.

```
                  <xsd:element name="Flight_No" type="xsd:int"/>
```

Do I need to modify the XML schema? or throw an exception in the Web service java code? or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebServiceTesterServlet` is expecting your `Flight_No` element to have a valid value.  Based on your XML schema is element is not allowed to be empty or absent, so you need to make sure it has a valid value like:

```
<Flight_No>123</Flight_No>
```

---

### UPDATE #1

**Support for Empty Element**

> is there a way to make it allowed to be empty?

In terms of XML Schema very few types support empty element.  The most common one that does is `xs:string`.

**Support for Absent Element**

Your element is required.  If you want to make it optional you can add the `minOccurs="0"` attribute.

```
<xsd:element name="Flight_No" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
```

**Representing Null in a Required Elenent**

You can indicate that your element is capable of representing null with the `nillable="true"` attribute.

```
<xsd:element name="Flight_No" type="xsd:int" nillable="true"/>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/binding-to-json-xml-handling-null.html

---

### UPDATE #2

> One last question... Is there a way to leave it required in the XML
>   schema but not when passing in parameters to the web service?

JAXB/JAX-WS is going to be able to handle the empty element correctly.  I'm not sure what you need to do to make `WebServiceTestServlet` happy.

Comment: is there a way to make it allowed to be empty?

Comment: @user2229747 - I have updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has helped loads.

Comment: One last question... Is there a way to leave it required in the XML schema but not when passing in parameters to the web service?

Comment: @user2229747 - JAXB/JAX-WS is going to be able to handle the empty element correctly.  I'm not sure what you need to do to make `WebServiceTestServlet` happy.